# How to trigger EVENT_FORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV in sim toolkit applet?

Tags: java, javacard, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I try to send a SMS message to trigger the events `EVENT_FORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV` and `EVENT_UNFORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV`, but it seems that it doesn't work. It doesn't send another message.

```
public void processToolkit(byte event) {
    case EVENT_FORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV:
        // send_another_msg();
        break;
    case EVENT_UNFORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV:
        // send_another_msg();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly register the both events with the help of toolkit registry, it will start to work correctly, kindly also take care about the TAR value.